# Is ther any collision between Genymotion and hardware device on Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, genymotion

**Is there any collision between Genymotion and hardware device on Android studio??** Yesterday, I tested my android phone as a debug machine on android studio. It worked perfectly. However, today, after installing genymotion and run my project on it, Android studio couldn't detect my phone....

I followed these steps :

1. check whether USB debugging is enabled
2. check sony xperia USB drive (I installed it from websites, and reinstalled it automatically after conneting my device)
3. reset Android device monitor
4. reboot my phone
5. reboot my computer
6. plug on/off usb cable

Comment: Collision? Shouldn't be. You can configure the app launcher to chose which device to run on if there are multiple that are connected

Comment: @cricket_007 okay.... ;~; I'll rather check other options

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no *collision* between Genymotion and hardware devices. But Genymotion does come with its own copy of `adb` which introduces potential `adb` client/server mismatch possibility. So just delete the `adb` binary from the `genymotion\tools` folder (you may need to kill all running `adb` processes first) and you should be ok.

Comment: If this solves your problem you should definitely ask Genymotion to use your adb from the Android sdk: Genymotion settings > adb > use custom sdk

Comment: @eyal-lezmy, the problem with leaving the `adb` binary in `genymotion\tools` folder is that sometimes `genymotion\tools` gets ahead of `ANDROID_HOME\platform-tools` in the `PATH` variable and genymotion's version of `adb` could still be launched inadvertently

Comment: @AlexP. Close all your genymotion devices, then open Genymotion Settings > ADB > use custom SDK and Genymotion will use **exclusively** the SDK's binary ;-)

Comment: Also, your solution will break things as it avoids the Genymotion device from being added automatically into "adb devices", and some feature like drag&drop won't be working anymore. You will need to find the good IP and do a "adb connect <ip>" to get your Genymotion device back.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy, reread my comment again. I am not being concerned with what genymotion would use.

Comment: So you don't care to not seeing your emulator on the "adb devices" right?

Comment: I do not use genymotion. I evaluated it some time ago and I found it lacking. You keep missing my point - changing the settings alone is not enough to make 100% sure that genymotion would not negatively affect the existing environment by introducing another version of `adb` binary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123441/discussion-between-eyal-lezmy-and-alex-p).